# Programmatically set banner view to fix to bottom of screen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, ios7

I have programmatically added a bannerView to my app. On iOS7 4" and 3.5" it works perfectly, however on iOS6, it moves the banner down by 20px, obviously because of the Status bar but I want the banner to always fit to the bottom of the screen, not fall 20 pixels off

My code is like this:

```
   [bannerView_ loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];


    [bannerView_ setFrame:CGRectMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width-bannerView_.frame.size.width,
                                     [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height-bannerView_.frame.size.height,
                                     bannerView_.frame.size.width,
                                     bannerView_.frame.size.height
                                     )];
```

Is there a way to programmatically change the deltas or something? Basically the banner needs to move 20px up on iOS6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIApplication` exposes `statusBarFrame`. That will give you the height of the status bar (normally, 20 **points**). You can then check if the user has iOS6 and offset the banner. Check by comparing `NSFoundationVersionNumber <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1`.

Try:

```
[bannerView_ setFrame:CGRectMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width - bannerView_.frame.size.width, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height - bannerView_.frame.size.height - (NSFoundationVersionNumber <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1 ? [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height : 0), bannerView_.frame.size.width, bannerView_.frame.size.height)];
```

Keep in mind, if you want to support rotation, your task will get harder, as you'd have to position the view after rotation, and you'd need to use `statusBarFrame.width` in landscape.

Comment: Thanks Leo, but what's the code that I would use to set the height? Im pretty novice so if you could help with the code that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use auto layout you should just say that the banner view has a bottom alignment equal to its superviews bottom alignment. In Visual Format Language that would be "V:[bannerView_]|". Don't forget to add constraints for width, height, and horizontal position if you take this approach.

If you can't use auto layout, then you'll have to subtract the height of the status bar from your banners origin.

You can get the height of the status bar with [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame].size.height